# How can I pass a array of selectors from swift 3 file to objective-c(Bridging)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, selector, ios10

I need to send an array of selectors in bridging project(Objective-C Project) from swift class to objective-C class.

The code that i am using for accessing the selectors within for loop is as

selectorsArr is an NSArray

```
SEL sel = [(NSValue *)[selectorsArr objectAtIndex:loopCounter]pointerValue];
```

In swift class I am setting

```
let sel = #selector(functionName)

let vv =  NSValue(nonretainedObject: sel)

let sel1 = #selector(functionName2)
let vv1 =  NSValue(nonretainedObject: sel2)
```

When I am trying this way it is crashing and the log is

"NSForwarding: warning: selector () for message '' does not match selector known to Objective C runtime ()-- abort"

"[ProjectName.SwiftClassName ]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Could some one say me the approach to follow